# Oracle replication possibilities

Tags: oracle, replication

I need to replicate Oracle database into one way. Data in replica will be only for the read.
Due to some limitations I cannot use Oracle Streams, Golden Gate and other commercial solutions.

What other possibilities do we have to perform that?

Comment: How often do you want to refresh the data in the read-only database?

Comment: @APC ideally as often as possible, but still it shouldn't be real-time replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialized views over database link might be one option.

Or, perhaps you could even consider exporting & importing data (using Data Pump utilities).

Comment: I've read about materialized views and will investigate that way. But really, I dint thought just about data export/import. Thanks!